# Problems accessing websites in Netherlands

Tags: vpn, proxy, vps

I have problems accessing certain websites in Netherlands, I have tried using several VPN, RDP, SOCK5(Vip72), Epic privacy browser. By the way i am in Asia (Malaysia). I used to be able to access it with VIP72, and changing my mac address with a mac spoofer. But doesn't work anymore for Netherlands, but for other EU countries.

My questions are;

1. whats the best way to access blocked websites? I read an article here about setting up a vpn on a vps, but I don't think that will do any good.
2. i also read about 4g/3g mobile data rentals? but is too expensive considering i just need to surf certain websites.

Comment: Opera's browsec. You can freely choose 4 different proxies directly from the extension's menu.

Comment: Questions asking for product recommendations are off-topic here. so I removed that part of your question.

Comment: sorry didnt realize that

Answer (score 2):

I believe those sites are detecting you have a VPN or proxy in place, and responding accordingly. It haven't anything do to with the country, but the site administrators.

> changing my mac address

This is irrelevant. You MAC address don't leave your local network anyway.

> I read an article here about setting up a vpn on a vps, but I dont think that will do any good

It can work or not, depending on the site administrators. If they detect your IP is from a range used by a VPS company, they can block you. You can rent a VPS on a small, cheap and unknown provider for a month and test. You can find hosting for a dollar a month, so it's worth testing.

You can try any VPN provider too, most of them have a free tier, or a trial period  when you can test the service and cancel without being billed. You can try those too. They are easier than to setup and maintain your own VPN, but are more expensive. On the other hand, maintaining a VPS can be very educative.

Comment: Thanks and i did try a VPS company, worked for a couple of weeks then boom. anyone used the 4G/3g rentals? private VPN? or am i doing something wrong?